# How to add an item in a metadata column into termstore?

Tags: metadata, sharepoint-2013, taxonomy

I have configured a managed metadata service and added few term sets and terms. I then created a list with a metadata column which can use these terms. I am able to get hints for the terms in this column.

Now, My requirement is that when I add some item to this column which is not present in term store, it should be added back to the Term store thus enabling the two way functionality and from the next time I should get hints of this term also.

Can someone explain how this can be achieved. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: You can try to use Keywords functionality instead of metaddata column. Go to list settings -> Enterprise Metadata and Keywords Settings -> and check "Add an Enterprise Keywords column to this list and enable Keyword synchronization" and press ok. This will add "Keywords" column to your list with auto fill in functionality.

Comment: Another way is to go to your column settings and allow "Fill in" choices. Then when you add or edit item in term picker dialog you will see "Add new item" link which allows you to add term to termset using this dialog instead of going to term store manager.

Comment: Thank you so much Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets...the second way is what I am looking for...It worked great. I appreciate your time and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following:
Go to your column settings and allow "Fill in" choices. Then when you add or edit item in term picker dialog you will see "Add new item" link which allows you to add term to termset using this dialog instead of going to term store manager.